# CSS to style last-child in a List

Tags: php, css, css-selectors

I have a list generated by php from an sql table, I'm trying to add some css to the last `<li>` but it affects all the `<li>`'s.
Is there something I don't understand or is it something specific in my code?

**php:**

```
echo "<ul>";
        if($row['sender'] == $userid) {
            echo "<li class='bubble' style='background: #4cd964;'><p>" . $text . "</p></li>";
        } else {
            echo "<li class='bubble' style='background: #ffcc00;'><p>" . $text . "</p></li>";
        }
        echo "</ul>";
```

**css:**

```
.bubble {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    left: 45%;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    border-radius:50%;
}
.bubble:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 20%;
}
```

Comment: So where is your code?

Comment: just use `li:last-child { /*code*/}`

Comment: That's what I'm doing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP code outputs only one line, one LI with either #4cd964 or #ffcc00 as the background color. I don't see any iteration structure to output more lines. If your iteration is OUTSIDE the `<UL>...</UL>` block, then you are outputting as many lists as there are iterations... meaning that :last-child applies to each and every LI on your page.

Please post complete PHP code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with your:

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li class="bubble">child 1</li>
  <li class="bubble">child 1</li>
  <li class="bubble">child 1</li>
  <li class="bubble">last child</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
li.bubble:last-child{
  color: red
}
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9x9uoeu9/)

**Result**

[image]

Comment: No good... I think it might be because the list is generated by the php. Is that possible?

Comment: no matter from where the list is generated, it will always work.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
li.bubble:last-child{
  color: red
}
```

If it doesn't try:

```
li.bubble:last-child p{
  color: red
}
```

And it must mean that your `<p>` has a defined color somewhere else in your css  that has a higher specificity value.